# How to make radio button from textbox code asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello i am working in asp.net mvc and i have this model done ready by the IDE the form is good and works it uploads the data on database. But insead of a textbox i want to make radio button. This is my code that makes the textbox:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gjinia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gjinia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Anyone knows how to make a radio button that will still work when inserting in the database?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of letting the framework choose an input type with `EditorFor` you can specify `RadioButtonFor` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of EditorFor you should use RadioButtonFor to change textbox into radiobutton.

For example:
Male:   @Html.RadioButton("Gender","Male")
Female: @Html.RadioButton("Gender","Female")